# Error while integrating node js code to cpp library

Tags: c++, node.js, node-ffi

I am trying to [node-ffi](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi) library to call a cpp code.

**CPP Code**

```
typedef struct{
    char * key,
    char * value
} ContextAttribute;

typedef struct{
    ContextAttribute * attribute,
    int count
} Context;
```

This is used in

```
Status Init(     
    Handle* handle,       
    const char* id,    
    const char* token, 
    const char* apiKey,
    const char* productname,          
    const char* productVersion,        
    const char* productLanguage,       
    PlatformType platform,             
    const char* userGuid,              
    EventCb eventcb,
    Context * context
);
```

I am consuming the above cpp code by the following **node-ffi** javascript code

```
var ref = require('ref');
var ffi = require('ffi');
var Struct = require('ref-struct');

var ContextAttribute = new Struct({
    key: "string",
    value: "string"
});

var Context = new Struct({
    attribute: ref.refType(ContextAttribute),
    count: "int"
});

'Init': [Status, [
        ref.refType(voidPtr),
        'string',
        'string',
        'string',
        'string',
        'string',
        'string',
        PlatformType,
        'string',
        EventCb,
        ref.refType(Context)
    ]],
```

The function is called as under

```
this.Init(clientId, token, apiKey, productName, productVersion, productLanguage, platform, userGuid, Event, wrapAsNative(callback), Context)
```

I am trying to test this using

```
var context = [{
    attribute: [{
         key: 'os',
         value: 'win'
    }],
    count: 0
}];

var result = Lib.Init("myClient", testToken, '4d84247c36bd4f63977853eb1e0cb5b7', "asfasd",'12','en_US', 'MAC', 'abcd+1@pqr.com', 'SIGNIN', function(Handle, Event){
}, context);
```

I am getting the following error :

> TypeError: error setting argument 10 - writePointer: Buffer instance
>   expected as third argument
>       at TypeError (native)
>       at Object.writePointer (/Users/..../node_modules/ref/lib/ref.js:742:11)
>       at Object.set (/Users/.../node_modules/ffi/ref/lib/ref.js:484:13)
>       at Object.alloc (/Users/.../node_modules/ffi/lib/ref.js:516:13)
>       at Object.proxy [as Init] (/Users/.../node_modules/ffi/lib/_foreign_function.js:50:22)
>       at Object.Lib.Init (/Users/.../src/Lib.js:130:26)

Comment: Your question don't contain enough information to answer you, please take the time to do a proper [mcve] and you will maybe solve your problem yourself ! `wrapAsNative(callback)` is probably wrong.

Comment: wrapAsNative(callback) is correct (because I get no error if I don't pass the struct), I want to pass context object in Lib.init() function this context object(javascript) need to be compatible with above given Struct of C.

Comment: You need to provide a gitrepo, else this like blind guess work

Comment: You need to share the code of  `/Lib.js` file Line 130:26

Answer (score 1):

```
var context = [{
    attribute: [{
         key: 'os',
         value: 'win'
    }],
    count: 0
}];
```

That is not how you create a valid `Buffer` object with `Context` layout. You must use `var context = new Context;` to create a correctly typed object.

That's exactly what the error message tells you - `context` is not a valid `Buffer`.

Not sure about it, but I don't think `ref` supports C-style arrays either, so a pointer + count struct doesn't work like that. If you want to use them, you will have to do that on the C side, and treat the array as an opaque pointer type.

(Not actually true, it is possible. But it requires fiddling around with the offset parameter on the `get`and `set` methods of the raw `Buffer` instance.)

Linked lists do work though.

Comment: seems to be a valid explaination, I will give your suggestion a try. One small doubt that still exists ... how to create Allocate memory for Array of Struct using node-ffi as you can see above attribute is array of struct.

Comment: @AurA Arrays are not supported by `ref-struct`. You would have to go on a raw `Buffer` and address by offset manually.